# Parameter estimates for skew normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, skewness, skew-normal-distribution

What are the formulaic parameter estimates for the skew-normal? If you can, the derivation via MLE or Mom would be great too.
Thanks

**Edit**.

I have a set of data for which I can tell visually by plots is slightly skewed to the left.   I want to estimate the mean and variance and then do a goodness-of-fit test (which is why I need the parameter estimates). Am I right in thinking I just have to guess the skew(alpha) (maybe do several skews and test for which is best?).

I would like the MLE derivation for my own understanding - would prefer MLE over MoM as I am more familiar with it.
I was unsure that there was more than one generic skew normal - I just mean a neg skewed mean! If possible, the skew exponential power param estimates would be helpful too!

Comment: (1) which parameterization of which specific 'skew-normal'? (I've seen more than one thing get called that) (2) when you say "the formulaic parameter estimates" you imply (a) a closed form exists and (b) that there's only one --- yet you mention both ML and MoM, which won't generally be the same (& the ML estimators in particular might not be closed form). More information is required!

Comment: See, for instance, the paper by Vinod: _Skew Densities and Ensemble Inference for Financial Economics_, which illustrates how to fit data to a skew-Normal: http://mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i4/SkewDensities.html

Comment: In R, `snormFit` in `fGarch` will estimate a skew normal distribution, or you might prefer to look at the `sn` package (uses Azzalini's definition, beware that other definitions of "skew normal" exist). If you use Stata, try [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0207). [Various packages](http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/index.html) for Python, VBA and Perl are available from the site of Adelchi Azzalini at the University of Padua.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, the "skew-normal family" has exploded in membership (the wikipedia article does *not* attest to this). So, let's consider the mother of them all, that has probability density function

$$f_X(x) = \frac{2}{\omega}\phi\left(\frac{x-\xi}{\omega}\right)\Phi\left(\alpha \left(\frac{x-\xi}{\omega}\right)\right)$$
where $\phi()$ is the standard normal pdf and $\Phi()$ the standard normal cdf. $\xi$ is the location parameter, $\omega$ is the scale parameter, and $\alpha$ is the skew parameter.

Closed-form solutions for the ML estimator do not exist. Method-of-Moments estimator provides closed forms as follows, assuming that all three parameters are non-zero (obviously if $\omega$ and/or $\xi$ are zero, then the steps below are simplified):

**1)** Obtain a MoM estimate  $\hat \delta$ by solving for $\delta$ the expression for the skewness of the distribution,
$$\gamma_3 = \frac{4 - \pi}{2} \frac{\left(\delta \sqrt{2/\pi} \right)^3}{\left(1 - 2\delta^2/\pi\right)^{3/2}}$$
using the estimated sample skewness coefficient $\hat \gamma_3$.

**2)** Obtain an estimate $\hat \alpha$ using

$$\delta = \frac {\alpha}{\sqrt {(1+\alpha^2)}} \implies \hat \alpha = \frac {\hat \delta}{\sqrt{1-\hat \delta^2}}$$

**3)** Obtain a MoM estimate $\hat \omega$ by solving for $\omega$ the expression for the variance,
$$\hat \sigma^2_x = \omega^2\cdot \left(1-\frac{2\hat \delta^2}{\pi}\right)$$
using the sample variance and the estimated $\delta$ derived in the previous step

**4)** Obtain a MoM estimate $\hat \xi$ by solving for $\xi$ the expression for the mean of the distribution,
$$\hat \mu_x = \xi + \hat \omega \hat \delta\sqrt {2/\pi}$$
using the sample mean and the previous estimates.

And don't forget to propagate estimation error in this sequential procedure, as regards the estimator variance.